# MySQL avoiding null values for sum operations?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, boolean-logic, isnull

I need to make a column that counts the amount of variables which are above 0, and that won't return null if there is any non-null value in it, for each value in an id column.

What I managed to make is using a sum between some boolean operations:

`IF 'A' THEN 'B' ELSE 'C'` (at least that's what I've got)

```
select ID, `jul`, `aug`, `set`, `oct`, `nov`, `dec`,
((((not `jul`) or 1) and (`jul` or 0)) 
+(((not `aug`) or 1) and (`aug` or 0))
+(((not `set`) or 1) and (`set` or 0))
+(((not `out`) or 1) and (`out` or 0))
+(((not `nov`) or 1) and (`nov` or 0))
+(((not `dec`) or 1) and (`dec` or 0))) as sum from table;
```

It works at first view, but if there is any null value in a line, the `sum` returns null for each respective id.

What could I do to avoid this problem?

Comment: "set" should prolly be "sep", btw...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
SUM( IFNULL(jul,0)+IFNULL(ago,2) ) as sum from table

/* 
   obs: the SUM is good to sum multiple values
   IFNULL returns 0 to the sum if jul is null and 2 for ago if ago is null in the example.
*/
```

i think it works. :)

Comment: the ifnull did help me with my case. At first, using it did a sum of the variables, but since i wanted de sum their boolean values (sums of 0s and 1s), i combined it with my logical operations and it worked ^^


ifnull((((not `jul`) or 1) and (`jul` or 0)),0)

Comment: I also wanted for the sum to show null for everytime all of its variables have null values, is there a way for such?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `coalesce` or variant to deal with nulls.  Null value represents an unknown.  You can't add unknowns and get something other than an unknown.

```
NULL + 1 = NULL
COALESCE(NULL, 0) + 1 = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `isnull(columnname, 0)` to turn nulls into 0s. So `isnull('jul',0)+isnull('aug',0)` etc.